# Animate by reducing the actual value of the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to change the top position of the element by reducing 30px for each element.

Let's say that I want 50px to be 20px and 100px to be 70px and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the actual height of the elements, or reduce the distance from the top?

Comment: The position as i said

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-=` notation to reduce the current value of an attribute. Try this:

```
$('#foo').animate({ top: '-=30px' }, 1000);
```

Note, `1000` is the number of miliseconds the animation will take to complete and can be amended as required.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".elementClass").animate({"top": "-=30"}, 500);`

`30` is the number of pixels to reduce the height by. `500` is the number of milliseconds for the animation.

A working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JNUUs/

I added `.delay(500)` to wait 500ms before animating.